# Gaussian process: Significance of a finite vs infinite set of indices

Tags: gaussian-process

The [definition of a Gaussian process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process#Definition) references a *finite* set of indices. What is the significance of using a finite set of indices, rather than allowing a countable (and thus potentially infinite) set of indices? If one tried to define a Gaussian process in terms of an infinite set of indices, would that cause problems further down the road?

Comment: Could you indicate how one might attempt a definition "in terms of an infinite set of indices"?  Bear in mind [Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem).

Comment: @whuber thank you, I was not aware of Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem. However, my problem seems to be that I don't understand why that theorem, and thus also GPs, can not *trivially* be applied to countably infinite sets. Is it for example because the probability measure of an infinite-dimensional set is nonsensical, or because the permutations of an infinite set is nonsensical? (as it might be apparent, my probability theory is too weak to fully appreciate the problem here)

Comment: The difficulty lies in creating a rigorous definition of a probability distribution over a set of functions (each of which is one possible realization of a stochastic process). One needs measure theory to do this: you have to create a suitable sigma algebra over the realizations and construct a probability distribution over that sigma algebra. In the process it's easy to create inconsistent requirements.  Working with *finite-dimensional* random variables that approximate the stochastic process is therefore quite appealing--and practical.

Comment: I see - that makes things a lot clearer, and essentially answers my question! If you convert that comment to an answer, I will accept it.